# MaraDNS does not respond to A record queries of locally-connected RFC1918 addresses

Tags: domain-name-system

We are running MaraDNS 2.0.06 on a CentOS 6 server.  We are set up as an authoritative server, and not offering recursion.

I have a mararc.base like this:

```
ipv4_bind_addresses = "192.168.50.250"
synth_soa_origin = "ns1.teamunify.net"
maradns_uid = 65500
maradns_gid = 65500
chroot_dir = "/etc/maradns"
default_rrany_set = 15
verbose_level = 2
hide_disclaimer = "yes"
tcp_convert_acl = "0.0.0.0/0"
tcp_convert_server = "192.168.50.250"
recursive_acl = "192.168.50.0/24, 10.10.0.0/16, 127.0.0.1"
csv2 = {}
```

I have added a record to the teamunify.com.zone file like this:

```
topica.%      192.168.50.141 ~
```

I am able to get the A record returned when I query the server from the local subnet.  I am not able to get the A record returned when I query the server remotely.

Logging at verbose_level = 3 shows that MaraDNS does receive the query:

```
Query from: $PUBLIC_IP Atopica.teamunify.com.
```

...but there are no errors in the log related to the query, and the client eventually times out.

We have other RFC1918 A records in that zone file, and all can return A records when queried remotely.  None of the working addresses are in the 192.168.50.0/24 subnet, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted this one out... here's the rundown:

- Authoritative name server running behind Cisco NAT Version 15.0(1r)M15, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
- configured NS to serve an A record for a 'local' subnet in rfc1918 addr space
- A record queries are never returned to the client!
- traffic analysis shows that the host actually sends the A record down the wire (toward NAT router)
- traffic analysis also shows that router is responding to A record answer with an ICMP host unreachable packet

Digging through cisco-nsp list yields this:
http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/cisco/nsp/84052

Also confirmed by this:
http://plone.lucidsolutions.co.nz/networking/cisco/ios/a-workaround-for-nat-rewriting-dns-packets

Fixing our nat translations for DNS to use the 'no-payload' directive allows the A record replies to transit the router.